# Setting cells of table to equal width

Tags: tables

What is the quickest way to set all the cells (under the `multicolumn`) to equal width? Here is my table code.

```
\begin{frame}{Applications}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
Origin & \multicolumn{7}{l|}{Development year}                  \\ \hline
Year   &$1$      & 2      & ... & j        & ... & n-1    & n    \\ \hline
1      & $X_{11}$    & $X_{12}$    & ... & $X_{1j}$      & ... & $X_{1,n-1}$ &     $X_{1,n}$ \\ \hline
2      & $X_{21}$    & $X_{22}$    & ... & $X_{2j}$      & ... & $X_{2,n-1}$ &          \\ \hline
...    & ...    & ...    & ... & ...      &     &        &      \\ \hline
i      & $X_{i1}$    & $X_{i2}$    & ... & $X_{i,n+1-i}$ &     &        &      \\     \hline
...    &        &        &     &          &     &        &      \\ \hline
n-1    & $X_{n-1,1}$ & $X_{n-2,1}$ &     &          &     &        &      \\ \hline
n      & $X_{n,1}$   &        &     &          &     &        &      \\ \hline
\end{tabular}  
\end{table}
```

Comment: Use the `tabularx` package and its eponymous environment instead of  the basic `tabular` environment.

Answer (score 8):

You can, but it won't fit in a `beamer` slide unless you reduce the font size and the intercolumn spaces.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{array}

\newlength{\mytabcell}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Applications}

\small
\settowidth{\mytabcell}{$X_{i,n+1-i}$}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-4pt}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\mytabcell}}

\begin{tabular}{|l|*{7}{P|}}
\hline
Origin & \multicolumn{7}{l|}{Development year} \\ \hline
Year   & $1$         & $2$         & \dots & $j$           & \dots & $n-1$       & $n$       \\ \hline
$1$    & $X_{11}$    & $X_{12}$    & \dots & $X_{1j}$      & \dots & $X_{1,n-1}$ & $X_{1,n}$ \\ \hline
$2$    & $X_{21}$    & $X_{22}$    & \dots & $X_{2j}$      & \dots & $X_{2,n-1}$ &           \\ \hline
\dots  & \dots       & \dots       & \dots & \dots         &       &             &           \\ \hline
$i$    & $X_{i1}$    & $X_{i2}$    & \dots & $X_{i,n+1-i}$ &       &             &           \\ \hline
\dots  &             &             &       &               &       &             &           \\ \hline
$n-1$  & $X_{n-1,1}$ & $X_{n-2,1}$ &       &               &       &             &           \\ \hline
$n$    & $X_{n,1}$   &             &       &               &       &             &           \\ \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The trick is to use a `p` column which we set the size with by telling it what's the widest column.

Note that the `table` environment serves no purpose. I also fixed the entries in math mode for consistency.

[image]

A possible improvement with `booktabs`

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\newlength{\mytabcell}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Applications}

\small
\settowidth{\mytabcell}{$X_{i,n+1-i}$}
\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{-4pt}
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\mytabcell}}

\begin{tabular}{l*{7}{P}}
\toprule
\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Origin\\Year\end{tabular}}
  & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Development year} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-8}
       & $1$         & $2$         & \dots & $j$           & \dots & $n-1$       & $n$       \\
\midrule
$1$    & $X_{11}$    & $X_{12}$    & \dots & $X_{1j}$      & \dots & $X_{1,n-1}$ & $X_{1,n}$ \\
$2$    & $X_{21}$    & $X_{22}$    & \dots & $X_{2j}$      & \dots & $X_{2,n-1}$ &           \\
\dots  & \dots       & \dots       & \dots & \dots         &       &             &           \\
$i$    & $X_{i1}$    & $X_{i2}$    & \dots & $X_{i,n+1-i}$ &       &             &           \\
\dots  &             &             &       &               &       &             &           \\
$n-1$  & $X_{n-1,1}$ & $X_{n-2,1}$ &       &               &       &             &           \\
$n$    & $X_{n,1}$   &             &       &               &       &             &           \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The actual improvement is using a matrix notation and save the whole slide in an equation I think.

Comment: @percusse Not a big difference.

Comment: I mean just mentioning the name X of the matrix not writing it out explicitly ;)

Comment: With [eqparbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/eqparbox) there is a way to automatize the discovery of the widest input (see §3.4-3.5 and other sections in its manual)

Comment: @jfbu Interesting, but perhaps overkill in this easy case.

Comment: I'd omit the `\cmidrule{1-1}` instruction, combine `Origin` and `Year`, and insert `\midrule` immediatetely below the ` & 1 & 2 ... & $n$` row.

Comment: @Mico Better now?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a modified version of @egreg's booktabs-based answer, in which I use a `tabular*` environment to let LaTeX do the work of figuring out the amount of intercolumn whitespace that sets the full table to `\textwidth`. With this setup, it turns out *not* to be necessary to reduce the font size in order to make the table fit inside the text block.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\newlength{\mytabcell}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Applications}

%\small
\settowidth{\mytabcell}{$X_{i,n+1-i}$}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.01pt} % let 'tabular*' figure out column separation
\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{\mytabcell}}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{7}{P}}
\toprule
\smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}l@{}}Origin\\Year\end{tabular}}
  & \multicolumn{7}{c}{Development year} \\
\cmidrule(l){2-8}
       & $1$         & $2$         & \dots & $j$           & \dots & $n-1$       & $n$       \\
\midrule
$1$    & $X_{11}$    & $X_{12}$    & \dots & $X_{1j}$      & \dots & $X_{1,n-1}$ & $X_{1,n}$ \\
$2$    & $X_{21}$    & $X_{22}$    & \dots & $X_{2j}$      & \dots & $X_{2,n-1}$ &           \\
\dots  & \dots       & \dots       & \dots & \dots         &       &             &           \\
$i$    & $X_{i1}$    & $X_{i2}$    & \dots & $X_{i,n+1-i}$ &       &             &           \\
\dots  &             &             &       &               &       &             &           \\
$n-1$  & $X_{n-1,1}$ & $X_{n-2,1}$ &       &               &       &             &           \\
$n$    & $X_{n,1}$   &             &       &               &       &             &           \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

With the environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, you have a key `columns-width` to fix the width of all the columns. With the value `auto`, the width will be the width of the widest cell of the array.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Applications}

\small
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}

\begin{NiceTabular}{lccccccc}[columns-width=auto,hvlines]
Origin & \Block[l]{1-*}{Development year} \\ 
Year   & $1$         & $2$         & \dots & $j$           & \dots & $n-1$       & $n$       \\ 
$1$    & $X_{11}$    & $X_{12}$    & \dots & $X_{1j}$      & \dots & $X_{1,n-1}$ & $X_{1,n}$ \\ 
$2$    & $X_{21}$    & $X_{22}$    & \dots & $X_{2j}$      & \dots & $X_{2,n-1}$ &           \\ 
\dots  & \dots       & \dots       & \dots & \dots       \\
$i$    & $X_{i1}$    & $X_{i2}$    & \dots & $X_{i,n+1-i}$ \\
\dots  \\
$n-1$  & $X_{n-1,1}$ & $X_{n-2,1}$ \\
$n$    & $X_{n,1}$   \\
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]